# If I only have 2 types of a model object, am I better off creating a `model_type` model or just adding a `type` attribute to my main model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Say I have a model `Banner`. I want the user to be able to upload 2 banners - `featured`, `side`.

Am I better off just creating a `Banner_Type` model or should I just add a `type` attribute to my `Banner` model?

If I am just adding a `type` attribute, how will I then query for those types?

What would the view look like, and the controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the right way is create a banner_type model, because it gives you the flexibility to add more banner types in future.

My suggestion is as follows:

### Tables

```
*banner_types*
id
type

*banners*
id
#your banner columns
banner_type_id
```

### Models

```
class BannerType < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :banners

end


class Banner < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :banner_type

end
```

### Controller

I'm not sure what you asked about the controller, but it will be just as normal controllers.

### View

You could call the banner type as, say you have a banner list

```
@banners.each do |banner|
  <p>
    <%= banner.banner_type.type%>
  </p>
end
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I decided to go with before u posted it. Thanks for the confirmation though.

Comment: @marcamillion, glad to help, rails rocks !!!!